# Generic API for Social Media Actions

Tags: c#, api, design-patterns, social-networking

I am creating a MVC4 website that needs to be integrated with multiple social networking platforms. The new OAuthWebSecurity class built into the framework has solved the problem of authentication and authorization.

My Model has objects of type Article and Comment. Both these objects are "sociable" i.e can be shared, posted liked etc

I am stuck at trying to figure an elegant implementation for this

Currently I have defined the following classes and Interfaces

ISocial - Defines the Minimum methods that a "sociable" type should implement

Article & Comment Implement ISocial

IProvider - Defines properties and methods for social media providers e.g AppId, AppSecret , and required end points

FacebookProvider & TwitterProvider Implement IProvider

The Networks that the current user has authorized is available with

OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name)

How can I Implement an GenericAPI (JSON) that  performs actions defined in ISocial

ie

Share() - Share/Tweet Article/Comment to User wall

Comment() - If article, Create new comment for article, If Comment, Post Reply to existing comment

Need implementation Suggestions and/or Critical Analysis for the proposed structure

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a note on managing your "Providers"; if your providers are going to be able to do the same things, But have different implementation you could adopt the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

**Description**

> In computer programming, the strategy pattern (also known as the
>   policy pattern) is a particular software design pattern, whereby an
>   algorithm's behaviour can be selected at runtime. Formally speaking,
>   the strategy pattern defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each
>   one, and makes them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary
>   independently from clients that use it.

In your case, the different 'algorithms' is the logic for each of the providers (e.g. The code to add a Comment on Facebook   or  the code to post a new Article on Google+).

In the example below the `SocialContext` is the object that is used to execute the generic functions for each Provider. You just need to set the Provider by calling `SetProvider(IProvider provider)`

Your API call methods could mimic the `SocialContext` methods along with some code to decide which Provider to use at runtime.

Heres an example in your case:

```
namespace StrategyPattern
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new SocialContext();

        context.SetProvider(new FacebookProvider()); //switch which provider you want to use

        context.AddComment(new Comment()
            {
                Message = "Heres my Comment!"
            });
    }
}


//providers

public interface IProvider
{
    void AddComment(Comment comment);
    void PostArticle(Article article);
}

public class FacebookProvider :IProvider
{
    public void AddComment(Comment comment)
    {
        //facebook implementation of "AddComment"
    }

    public void PostArticle(Article article)
    {
        //facebook implementation of "PostArticle"
    }
}

public class TwitterProvider : IProvider
{
    public void AddComment(Comment comment)
    {
        //twitter implementation of "AddComment"
    }

    public void PostArticle(Article article)
    {
        //twitter implementation of "PostArticle"
    }
}


public class Article
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public String Message { get; set; }
}



//context to use the providers

public class SocialContext
{
    private IProvider _provider;

    public void SetProvider(IProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public IProvider GetProvide { get { return _provider; } }

    public void AddComment(Comment comment)
    {
        _provider.AddComment(comment);
    }

    public void PostArticle(Article article)
    {
        _provider.PostArticle(article);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Mike .. Any way I can have a single Post method for article & comment .. I was thinking generics but I am not sure if I would be over complicating my code for novelty

Comment: Actually its not only novelty, I would like to be able to share a comment onto a user wall , the API call for that would be same, the content will differ based on object type, any way I can avoid having sharearticle and sharecomment and just have share instead

Comment: Theres no stopping you just having a Share(Item item) method on the IProvider. It seems you would like to use the same method that does different things with different objects. With this problem in mind - i would consider reviewing your design.

Comment: Pointers on the flaw with current design will be highly appriciated. Will happily mark this as an answer if you can point me to the right direction, (nnot that I don't appriciate the effort you have made already) .. any pattern tricks ?

Comment: it is actually performing the same function with all objects, May be I can create getPostData, getLikeData methods in Article class and comment class and call these, share(Item Item) will become share(IItem item) ..

Comment: Ii might be easier to give a better and more direct answer if you post some examples of your current code base.

Comment: I think we have already figured out the solution. Gimme 30 mins, Ill post an answer with code base. Will be highly obliged if you review it.

Comment: Unfortunately what I am trying is not really possible since API Calls for performing actions on different entities are different so I believe I will have to implement my requirements as you suggested. Am unable to vote up your reply since I do not have the required reputation (yet). Thank you Mike.

Comment: If you do make any progress, put a reply into this question so I can see your final solution. Good Luck! :)